# InfluxDB Flux query how to get distinct values from query

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux, k6

I have written the following Flux query in Grafana, I get two results for value. I would like to filter those two by distinct values by scenario key.

[image]

I would expect to have "main_flow" and "persons_end_user" results at the end. How can I achive this, I have tried with distinct() and unique(), but does not seem to work.

Comment: Are you trying to get distinct values over the two columns altogether?

Comment: Nope, need distinct only by scenario

Comment: `from(bucket: "proxiad")  
 |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop) 
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "iterations" and r.scenario =~ /.*/)
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
 |> group(columns: ["scenario"])
 |> keep(columns: ["scenario"])
 |> group()

 |> distinct(column: "scenario")`
This did the trick, but when passing it under the Grafana variables as a query I get no results, even tho the query returns the results in a table.